# more width is showing in mobile layout

Tags: html, css, layout, width, responsive

I am a back-end developer and so im not very familiar with front-end developing. recently due to absence of front end designer, i am designing a website in which i'm facing a problem.
this is a non-responsive website who looks fine in desktop, but in mobile the layout shows more than 100%, i'm attaching screenshots

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.top-all {
 margin: 0 auto;
  width: 900px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.top-header {
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #1A1318;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  position: relative;
}
.main-body {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 900px;
  background-color:  #ffffe6;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;


}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.logo-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: #E4E4E4;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  }
.container {
  width: 100%;
 background-color: #E8E8E8;
}

.main-left {
  width: 60%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color:  #ffffe6;
  
}
.main-right {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 36%;

}
.news {
 border: 1px solid  #d5ff80;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #f0f5f5;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: square;
}
ul li {
  color:#00001a;
  margin-top: 9px;
}
.announcement {
 border: 1px solid  #d5ff80;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #f0f5f5;
}
.quick-inquiry {
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid  #d5ff80;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: white;
}
h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", Courier, monospace;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: CENTER;
  color: white;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: arial;
  margin-right: 6px;
  margin-left: 6px;
}
h5 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 30px;
}
h6 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-left: 8px;
}
.h6 {
  padding-top: 1px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( #ffff66,#999900, #ffff66);
  height: 48px;
  width: 400px;
}
h7 {
  font-size: 26px;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 8px;
}
.h7 {
    padding-top: 3px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#706B6B,#000000,#706B6B);
  height: 50px;
}
h8{
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 8px;
 
}
.h8{
   padding: 4px;
  background-color: #006633;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#4dffa6,#006633,#4dffa6);
  height: 40px;
  width: 120px;
}
p{
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.p {
 background-color:  #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #b3b3ff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.h3 {
  background-color: black;
  height: 68px;
  margin-right: 7px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#706B6B,#000000,#706B6B);

}
marquee {
  border-top : 4px solid #ffff00;
  border-bottom : 4px solid #ffff00;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #0EB177;
}
.footer {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #150F0F;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #535151;
  background-color: #e6ffff;
  padding: 0px;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 99%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title>Patliputra ITI</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.navbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="top-all">
    <div class="top-header">
      <div class="logo-container">
        <img src="images/main_logo.png" style="height: 100px; width: 180px;" alt="logo">
  </div>
    <h1>Patliputra ITI</h1>
  </div>
 
<div class="navbar">
 <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">About Us</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact Us</a> 
  <a href="#about">News</a>
   <a href="#contact">Gallery</a> 
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-4.0.0.js"></script>
</div>

</div>
<div class="main-body">
  <div class="header">
  <h4>  "On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain."</h4>
  <div class="container">
  <h2>Welcome to Patliputra ITI</h2>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to
="3"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://images.static-collegedunia.com/public/college_data/images/appImage/19709_BBSBCE_APP.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Patliputra ITI</h3>
          <p>Patliputra ITI</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/1209519.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Patliputra ITI</h3>
          <p>Patliputra ITI</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.pixelstalk.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/College-Wallpapers-HD-1920x1080.jpg" alt="New York" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Patliputra ITI</h3>
          <p>Patliputra ITI</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://adrian.edu/uploads/galleries/TerraceWP.jpg" alt="New York" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Patliputra ITI</h3>
          <p>Patliputra ITI</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
 <marquee width="100%" direction="left" height="100px">
<h5>The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,</h5>
</marquee>
  <div class="main-left">
    <div class="h6"><h6>Why Patliputra ITI?</h6></div><div class="p"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at mi a odio maximus rutrum eget in justo. In in est metus. Duis efficitur dui euismod suscipit elementum. Nam gravida nisi metus, pretium aliquam justo porta non. Quisque semper fermentum sem at maximus. Proin fermentum mauris a lacus pellentesque interdum. Vestibulum sollicitudin augue ac dolor eleifend, mattis pretium eros auctor. Aliquam pharetra laoreet leo a accumsan. Pellentesque non mattis nisi. Vivamus quis congue risus.</p></div>
    <div class="h6"><h6>Our Mission And Vision</h6></div><div class="p"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at mi a odio maximus rutrum eget in justo. In in est metus. Duis efficitur dui euismod suscipit elementum. Nam gravida nisi metus, pretium aliquam justo porta non. Quisque semper fermentum sem at maximus. Proin fermentum mauris a lacus pellentesque interdum. Vestibulum sollicitudin augue ac dolor eleifend, mattis pretium eros auctor. Aliquam pharetra laoreet leo a accumsan. Pellentesque non mattis nisi. Vivamus quis congue risus.</p></div>
    <div class="h6"><h6> How to get Admission?</h6></div><div class="p"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at mi a odio maximus rutrum eget in justo. In in est metus. Duis efficitur dui euismod suscipit elementum. Nam gravida nisi metus, pretium aliquam justo porta non. Quisque semper fermentum sem at maximus. Proin fermentum mauris a lacus pellentesque interdum. Vestibulum sollicitudin augue ac dolor eleifend, mattis pretium eros auctor. Aliquam pharetra laoreet leo a accumsan. Pellentesque non mattis nisi. Vivamus quis congue risus.</p></div>
    <div class="h6"><h6>Eligibility</h6></div><div class="p"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at mi a odio maximus rutrum eget in justo. In in est metus. Duis efficitur dui euismod suscipit elementum. Nam gravida nisi metus, pretium aliquam justo porta non. Quisque semper fermentum sem at maximus. Proin fermentum mauris a lacus pellentesque interdum. Vestibulum sollicitudin augue ac dolor eleifend, mattis pretium eros auctor. Aliquam pharetra laoreet leo a accumsan. Pellentesque non mattis nisi. Vivamus quis congue risus.</p></div>
    <div class="h7"><h7>Admission process</h7></div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <div class="h8"><h8>Process 1</h8></div><div class="p"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at mi a odio maximus rutrum eget in justo. In in est metus. Duis efficitur dui euismod suscipit elementum. Nam gravida nisi metus, pretium aliquam justo porta non. Quisque semper fermentum sem at maximus.</p></div>
    <div class="h8"><h8>Process 2</h8></div><div class="p"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at mi a odio maximus rutrum eget in justo. In in est metus. Duis efficitur dui euismod suscipit elementum. Nam gravida nisi metus, pretium aliquam justo porta non. Quisque semper fermentum sem at maximus.</p></div>
    <div class="h8"><h8>Process 3</h8></div><div class="p"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at mi a odio maximus rutrum eget in justo. In in est metus. Duis efficitur dui euismod suscipit elementum. Nam gravida nisi metus, pretium aliquam justo porta non. Quisque semper fermentum sem at maximus.</p></div>

</div>
<div class="main-right">
  <div class="news">
   <div class="h3"><h3>Latest News</h3></div>
    <h4>Where can I get some?
There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour.</h4>
<ul class="ul_news">
  <li>News 1</li>
  <li>News 2</li>
  <li>News 3</li>
  <li>News 4</li>
  <li>News 5</li>
  <li>News 6</li>
  <li>News 7</li>
  <li>News 8</li>
  <li>News 9</li>
  <li>News 10</li>
</ul>
</div>
  <div class="announcement">
    <div class="h3"><h3>Latest Announcement</h3></div>
    <h4>Where can I get some?
There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always fre</h4></div>
  <div class="quick-inquiry">
<div class="h3"><h3>Quick-Inquiry</h3></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

desktop view of the site

[image]

mobile view of the site

[image]

Comment: add your HTML & CSS code here

Comment: done, can you please check them out?

Comment: you apply fixed width `900px` remove this or change to  `max-width`

Comment: remove the viewport meta tag, and it will default to desktop view, otherwise make the site responsive

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things you need to change:

1. Remove the inline-styles on the images in the slider
2. add a media query for mobile view
3. Remove the `display: inline-block; float: right;` on the news and the main-right container.
4. Remove the marquee tag, it's deprecated.

As already mentioned by someone else, change all the fixed widths to max-widths. 
Since you are also including bootstrap, I would make use of their grid system and classes for your layout and basic styling, otherwise remove it.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.top-all {
 margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 900px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.top-header {
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #1A1318;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  position: relative;
}
.main-body {
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 900px;
  background-color:  #ffffe6;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;


}
.header {
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.logo-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: #E4E4E4;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  }
.container {
 background-color: #E8E8E8;
}

.main-left {
  width: 60%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color:  #ffffe6;
  
}
.main-right {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 36%;
}
.news {
 border: 1px solid  #d5ff80;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #f0f5f5;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: square;
}
ul li {
  color:#00001a;
  margin-top: 9px;
}
.announcement {
 border: 1px solid  #d5ff80;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #f0f5f5;
}
.quick-inquiry {
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid  #d5ff80;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: white;
}
h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", Courier, monospace;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: CENTER;
  color: white;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: arial;
  margin-right: 6px;
  margin-left: 6px;
}
h5 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 30px;
}
h6 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-left: 8px;
}
.h6 {
  padding-top: 1px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( #ffff66,#999900, #ffff66);
  height: 48px;
  width: 400px;
}
h7 {
  font-size: 26px;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 8px;
}
.h7 {
    padding-top: 3px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#706B6B,#000000,#706B6B);
  height: 50px;
}
h8{
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 8px;
 
}
.h8{
   padding: 4px;
  background-color: #006633;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#4dffa6,#006633,#4dffa6);
  height: 40px;
  width: 120px;
}
p{
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.p {
 background-color:  #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #b3b3ff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.h3 {
  background-color: black;
  height: 68px;
  margin-right: 7px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#706B6B,#000000,#706B6B);

}
marquee {
  border-top : 4px solid #ffff00;
  border-bottom : 4px solid #ffff00;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #0EB177;
}
.footer {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #150F0F;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #535151;
  background-color: #e6ffff;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
 .main-left {
  background-color:  #ffffe6;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
 }
 .main-right {
  float: none;
   width: auto;
 }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title>Patliputra ITI</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.navbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="top-all">
    <div class="top-header">
      <div class="logo-container">
        <img src="images/main_logo.png" style="height: 100px; width: 180px;" alt="logo">
  </div>
    <h1>Patliputra ITI</h1>
  </div>
 
<div class="navbar">
 <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">About Us</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact Us</a> 
  <a href="#about">News</a>
   <a href="#contact">Gallery</a> 
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-4.0.0.js"></script>
</div>

</div>
<div class="main-body">
  <div class="header">
  <h4>  "On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain."</h4>
  <div class="container">
  <h2>Welcome to Patliputra ITI</h2>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to
="3"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://images.static-collegedunia.com/public/college_data/images/appImage/19709_BBSBCE_APP.jpg" alt="Chicago">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Patliputra ITI</h3>
          <p>Patliputra ITI</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/1209519.jpg" alt="Chicago">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Patliputra ITI</h3>
          <p>Patliputra ITI</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.pixelstalk.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/College-Wallpapers-HD-1920x1080.jpg" alt="New York">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Patliputra ITI</h3>
          <p>Patliputra ITI</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://adrian.edu/uploads/galleries/TerraceWP.jpg" alt="New York">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Patliputra ITI</h3>
          <p>Patliputra ITI</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
 <marquee width="100%" direction="left" height="100px">
<h5>The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,</h5>
</marquee>
  <div class="main-left">
    <div class="h6"><h6>Why Patliputra ITI?</h6></div><div class="p"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at mi a odio maximus rutrum eget in justo. In in est metus. Duis efficitur dui euismod suscipit elementum. Nam gravida nisi metus, pretium aliquam justo porta non. Quisque semper fermentum sem at maximus. Proin fermentum mauris a lacus pellentesque interdum. Vestibulum sollicitudin augue ac dolor eleifend, mattis pretium eros auctor. Aliquam pharetra laoreet leo a accumsan. Pellentesque non mattis nisi. Vivamus quis congue risus.</p></div>
    <div class="h6"><h6>Our Mission And Vision</h6></div><div class="p"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at mi a odio maximus rutrum eget in justo. In in est metus. Duis efficitur dui euismod suscipit elementum. Nam gravida nisi metus, pretium aliquam justo porta non. Quisque semper fermentum sem at maximus. Proin fermentum mauris a lacus pellentesque interdum. Vestibulum sollicitudin augue ac dolor eleifend, mattis pretium eros auctor. Aliquam pharetra laoreet leo a accumsan. Pellentesque non mattis nisi. Vivamus quis congue risus.</p></div>
    <div class="h6"><h6> How to get Admission?</h6></div><div class="p"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at mi a odio maximus rutrum eget in justo. In in est metus. Duis efficitur dui euismod suscipit elementum. Nam gravida nisi metus, pretium aliquam justo porta non. Quisque semper fermentum sem at maximus. Proin fermentum mauris a lacus pellentesque interdum. Vestibulum sollicitudin augue ac dolor eleifend, mattis pretium eros auctor. Aliquam pharetra laoreet leo a accumsan. Pellentesque non mattis nisi. Vivamus quis congue risus.</p></div>
    <div class="h6"><h6>Eligibility</h6></div><div class="p"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at mi a odio maximus rutrum eget in justo. In in est metus. Duis efficitur dui euismod suscipit elementum. Nam gravida nisi metus, pretium aliquam justo porta non. Quisque semper fermentum sem at maximus. Proin fermentum mauris a lacus pellentesque interdum. Vestibulum sollicitudin augue ac dolor eleifend, mattis pretium eros auctor. Aliquam pharetra laoreet leo a accumsan. Pellentesque non mattis nisi. Vivamus quis congue risus.</p></div>
    <div class="h7"><h7>Admission process</h7></div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <div class="h8"><h8>Process 1</h8></div><div class="p"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at mi a odio maximus rutrum eget in justo. In in est metus. Duis efficitur dui euismod suscipit elementum. Nam gravida nisi metus, pretium aliquam justo porta non. Quisque semper fermentum sem at maximus.</p></div>
    <div class="h8"><h8>Process 2</h8></div><div class="p"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at mi a odio maximus rutrum eget in justo. In in est metus. Duis efficitur dui euismod suscipit elementum. Nam gravida nisi metus, pretium aliquam justo porta non. Quisque semper fermentum sem at maximus.</p></div>
    <div class="h8"><h8>Process 3</h8></div><div class="p"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at mi a odio maximus rutrum eget in justo. In in est metus. Duis efficitur dui euismod suscipit elementum. Nam gravida nisi metus, pretium aliquam justo porta non. Quisque semper fermentum sem at maximus.</p></div>

</div>
<div class="main-right">
  <div class="news">
   <div class="h3"><h3>Latest News</h3></div>
    <h4>Where can I get some?
There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour.</h4>
<ul class="ul_news">
  <li>News 1</li>
  <li>News 2</li>
  <li>News 3</li>
  <li>News 4</li>
  <li>News 5</li>
  <li>News 6</li>
  <li>News 7</li>
  <li>News 8</li>
  <li>News 9</li>
  <li>News 10</li>
</ul>
</div>
  <div class="announcement">
    <div class="h3"><h3>Latest Announcement</h3></div>
    <h4>Where can I get some?
There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always fre</h4></div>
  <div class="quick-inquiry">
<div class="h3"><h3>Quick-Inquiry</h3></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```